# How to create Flash component without visible scene?

Tags: actionscript, audio, flash

I would like to integrate mp3 sound file into web-page using Flash, just to play it if some event occurs. It seems to me, the easiest way to do that is to integrate a small swf file into web-page and send path to mp3 file as parameter in  element. So basically swf gets path to mp3 file and plays it.

Is it possible to make flash element (swf file) without a picture or without scene? It looks like, flash element always need to have a visible screen, but I don't need it because my flash component doesn't need to show anything to a user.

**UPDATE:**
At this moment, I made 1x1px flash and hid it in HTML document, using `object` element.

```
  <object width="0" height="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try hiding it with css or jquery? or maybe make the BG colour of the swf the same as your webpage.

Comment: I hid it, however, don't think it is an option.

Comment: try this css: "visibility: hidden"

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make it float and transparent?

```
<object style="position: absolute; top: -1px; left: -1px;" width="1" height="1">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="thing.swf" wmode="transparent" width="1" height="1" />
</object>
```